# Unable to get Lat Long in samsung Mobile

Tags: java, android, gps

I am not getting current latitude and longitude in my "Samsung galaxy Ace" mobile using the code that you provided. What would be the reason?

Comment: please fill up question with some code you are trying so that we can figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the option for location to be retrieved is checked on in the device settings.

Settings> Location and security > Use wireless networks + Use GPS satellites

Also make sure you have the relevant permissions in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```